# How to change style of some texts to style of Heading 1 without affect rest of text

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to change the format of some text that have font size = 20 and font name = "Times New Roman" to style of "Heading 1"

The issue is, for example the text is centered and doing manually when Heading 1 is selected the text is sent to left and changed its font size, font name and font color
to those that Heading 1. Then, once the text is related with "Heading 1" I can centered again and set the same format options as before and the text remains related with "Heading 1"

I tried to make this with VBA in order to applyt the same as above to all text with size 20 and font "Times New Roman", but my code below it seems to affect the other text within document
even that text has different font size.

How can I fix this problem?

```
Sub ChangeToHeading1()
Dim wdDoc As Document

Set wdDoc = ActiveDocument

    With wdDoc.Range
        .Find.ClearFormatting
        .Find.Font.Size = 20
        .Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Find.Text = ""
        .Find.Replacement.Text = ""
        .Find.Replacement.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1")
        .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
        .Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
        .Font.Size = 20         
        .Find.Forward = True
        .Find.Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Find.Format = True
        .Find.MatchCase = False
        .Find.MatchWholeWord = False
        .Find.MatchWildcards = False
        .Find.MatchSoundsLike = False
        .Find.MatchAllWordForms = False
        .Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have three lines of code where you have omitted the .find. this means that you are applying the formatting to wdDoc.Range directly rather than as part of the .find construct.

Comment: Instead of overriding the heading 1 format with hard coding, change the font definitions in the Heading 1 Style.

Comment: @macropod I changed manually previously the format desired in Heading 1. I changed the color of Heading 1 too. I recorded this macro `Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1")` When I select a text and manually apply "Heading 1" the text changes to the font style (size, name, color) of Heading 1, but when I play the macro recorded the color doesn't change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you haven't bothered to tell us what colour you want the Heading 1 Style to be, we can only guess. You really ought also spend a bit of time learning how to use VBA, not just the macro recorder - there are also innumerable examples of the kinds of code you need all over the web. For example:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument
  With .Styles(wdStyleHeading1)
    .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
    .Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
    .Font.Size = 20
    .Font.ColorIndex = wdGreen
  End With
  With .Range.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Text = ""
    .Font.Size = 20
    .Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Replacement.Style = wdStyleHeading1
    .Format = True
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi macropod. Thanks for the help. With my limited time I try to learn not only using macro recorder. Actually in VBA for word I'm very new, I have a little bit more experience in VBA for Excel. Regarding the color I didn´t think it was so important, but you guessed, is Green hehe. Your solution it works, the only issue is that in the document, I have 2 font.names, so to apply only to those with size 20 pt and type "Time New Roman" I added in block `With .Range.Find .. End With` the line `.Font.Name = "Times New Roman"`, but adding this it doesn´t change anything. Why I'm doing wrong?

Comment: When I run this macro http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=137 to print the fonts used in the document I get this result `The fonts in this document are:
 Times New Roman, 
Calibri, 
Goudy Old Style`

Comment: I tested with another document with same fonts and sizes and with that document it works, I´m not sure why is not working with the other document. I´ll continue checking. Thanks for the help again!

Comment: The mere fact your document might contain 20pt content and Times New Roman content *does not* automatically mean it contains 20pt Times New Roman content.

Comment: That is easy to confirm. I select the text and in Home/Font area, MS-Word reports `Times New Roman, 20` so, the reason why is not working is other.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want Heading 1 to be in 20 point Times New Roman and centered. So just modify the style to have the settings you want before you apply it in your find.

```
Sub ModifyHeading1()
  With ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleHeading1)
    With .Font
      .Name = "Times New Roman"
      .Size = 20
    End With
    .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
  End With
End Sub

Sub ChangeToHeading1()
Dim wdDoc As Document

Set wdDoc = ActiveDocument

    With wdDoc.Range.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Font.Size = 20
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Replacement.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1")
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I changed manually previously the format desired in Heading 1.  I changed the color of Heading 1 but I'm not sure why it seems to replace the style of text I want, but the color is not changed.